# Start-Process MSI Installation with Feature Selection

Tags: powershell

I need to quietly install an .msi that has a feature selection. I have identified the feature name (by logging a verbose output and looking for the ADDLOCAL value) but using start-process or msiexec in PowerShell doesn't seem to work.

I can install .msi's that don't have feature selection using start-process without issue.

Here is my PowerShell to install the .msi containing a feature selection:

```
Start-Process "C:\packages\msodbcsql13_1x64.msi" /qn ADDLOCAL=SQL_SQLODBC_CORE -Wait
```

The error I receive is as follows:

> Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts
>   argument '/ADDLOCAL=SQL_SQLODBC_CORE'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Start-Process "C:\packages\msodbcsql13_1x64.msi" /qn /ADDLOCAL=SQL_SQL ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Start-Process], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartProcessCommand

Answer (score 2):

Don't try too hard. PowerShell is a shell. It can run commands when you just type them, such as `msiexec`.

```
msiexec /i C:\packages\msodbcsql13_1x64.msi ADDLOCAL=SQL_SQLODBC_CORE /qb
```

Of course, quote any parameters that contain spaces.

Comment: What’s the difference between qb and qn in this example? I tried this with qn but it failed

Comment: You too can [look up the parameters for msiexec.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367988.aspx).

Comment: I was always partial to `/qb-!` so there's no "I'm done!" message at the end, and no cancel button just in case it's visible to the user so they don't cancel my install and screw things up.

Comment: Thanks, the end goal is to execute this remotely (by calling PowerShell script that contains the MSI installs)